# The hessian of a function - how to find the maximum or minimum

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am taking Calculus 3 and in the last class the professor say that we can use the hessian of a function to see which is the minimum and or maximum of a function...

The problem is that I don't understand exactly what the hessian means, and how I can use it to calculate a minimum or maximum.

Can someone explain me a little bit with a step-by-step example?
Also, How I know that it is definitive positive or definitive negative??

Thanks.

Comment: Look for examples in the site. I've found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74911/find-extremes-of-function-fx-y-z-x2y-y2z-x-z?rq=1) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122410/local-extreme-value-saddle-point-multi-variable-calculus?rq=1) so far. Also a google search should help with finding examples, hell, even youtube.

Comment: @Edwardo His teacher has mensionou the concept of convex function of several variables? Are you familiar with the Taylor approximation of functions of several variables? Please be specific about what you have to on these issues for family members to MathExchage can help you.

Comment: @E.Costa the professor said soemthing, but not in depth. So I am not familiar with the taylor series for multivariables. No, he dont mention the concept of convex... :(

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f:\ \Omega\to{\mathbb R}^2$ has continuous second partial derivatives in a region $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^n$, and that ${\bf p}\in\Omega$ is a *critical point* of $f$, i.e., that $\nabla f({\bf p})={\bf 0}$. Then Taylor's theorem applied at ${\bf p}$ says that
$$f({\bf p}+{\bf X})-f({\bf p})=\sum_{i, k=1}^n h_{ik}\ X_i\>X_k+\ o\bigl(|{\bf X}|^2\bigr)\qquad({\bf X}\to{\bf 0})\ ,\tag{1}$$
where the symmetric matrix $H:=[h_{ik}]$ given by
$$h_{ik}:={\partial^2 f\over\partial x_i\partial x_k}\biggr|_{\bf p}$$
is the so-called *Hessian* of $f$ at the critical point ${\bf p}$.

When this Hessian, resp., the quadratic form $$h({\bf X}):=\sum_{i, k=1}^n h_{ik}\ X_i\>X_k\ ,$$ is, say, *positive definite*, i.e., assumes a positive value at all points ${\bf X}\ne{\bf 0}$, then it assumes a positive minimum $\mu>0$ on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, and from $(1)$ it follows that
$$f({\bf p}+{\bf X})-f({\bf p})\geq |{\bf X}|^2\bigl(\mu+o(1)\bigr)\qquad ({\bf X}\to{\bf 0})\ .$$
But this says that for all sufficiently short ${\bf X}\ne{\bf 0}$ we have $f({\bf p}+{\bf X})-f({\bf p})>0$, in other words: that we have a local minimum at ${\bf p}$.

Testing the matrix $H$ for definiteness is a problem of linear algebra, and I won't go into it. When $H$ is only "semidefinite" it is usually difficult to decide whether we have a local extremum at ${\bf p}$. When $H$ is *indefinite*, i.e., assumes positive and negative values, then we certainly don't have an extremum at ${\bf p}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The Hessian is the matrix consisting of second order partial derivatives (compare it to the Jacoby matrix, which is similar, but then for first order partial derivatives). How can you use the second derivative in finding a maximum/minimum?

Additional Hint: The sign of the second derivative tells you whether something is a maximum or a minimum. A negative second deravitive implies a maximum and vice versa. To determine the maximum or minimum, you will also need to make use of the first derivative.

Comment: I dont know what is the Jacombian matrix but, If I find the determinant that is positive, it is definitive positive? if it is negative, means definitive negative? what if is 0? Which is the maxima or minima? (how to find it) give me a simple example please :P